# Using SSH private key 1.1 on Tamir .Net SSH library

Tags: c#, ssh-keys, private-key, sharpssh

I'm tasked with replacing a Unix Java application that loads files onto a SSH server with a C#.Net application using Tamir's OpenSSH library.  The SSH server accepts a key that uses "SSH PRIVATE KEY FILE FORMAT 1.1", which Tamir's library doesn't understand.  Does anyone know what Windows tools can convert this key, or a .Net library that can read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I was granted access to the account and was able to generate a new key that the library can read.

Comment: There were still a few wrinkles.  Here's a list for anyone who is attempting this specific combination:
 
1. Generate an SSH-2-RSA public key by PuttyGen
 
2. Register the public key on the SFTP server
3. Save the private key in putty Format
4. Use WinSCP to connect to the sftp server using the private key generated in the step 3 

5. If the connection works, You will have to load the private key generated in the step 3 and  convert it to OpenSSh format. 

6. Use the private key generated in step 5, make sure that the authentication parameters are right, then test the tamirSftp connection.